# What does peer_connection.onicecandidate() function do?what is an ice_event?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am having difficulty in understanding the puropse of onicecandidate function.
How does the ice candidates helps in establishing the peer connection.And who sends the ice candidates first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Under the hood, webrtc gather local candidate depending on the available network connections, and the list of ice servers passed to it through the JS API.
- once a ice candidate is ready, it is provided to the JS layer through the onicecandidate API.
- if you're using trickle ICE, you can then send the candidate right away through the signaling path to the remote peer. Otherwise, wait for the last (null) candidate, order them by priority, add them to the offer/answer sdp, and send the offer/answer through the signaling path. This is usually done automatically for you by the browser.
- You might to look at the handshake specifications here:
  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-09

Answer (score 1):

The peer device won't be able to stream media to other peer using its own private IP. So we need NAT-traversing server (ICE server) maps private IP to public one.

So the the client application should ask ICE server for his own ICE candidates "which is the public id".

First the caller will ask for his public IP (ICE candidate) and send it to the other peer via signaling server.

When the other guy receive the candidates, he asked the ICE server about his own candidate also and send it back to the caller.

when both peers have each other ice candidates (public IPs) so they can do P2P streaming.

[image]

**ICE problems**

20% ICE server - STUN protocol will fails in providing public IP. Because either both media devices located behind symmetric NAT! or P2P traffic blocked by firewall!

In that case P2P streaming won't be reliable!
To solve these we must use an external media relay server – TURN server which is a protocol supported by ICE server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
connection.onicecandidate = function(newRTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) {

    // a new candidate has been created
    var newRTCIceCandidate = newRTCPeerConnectionIceEvent.candidate;
    // could send this to the remote peer
};
```

The candidate represents a destination (sending or receiving) for a media stream and in the SDP will look something like this:

```
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706431 10.0.1.1 8998 typ host
```